# Telerik Report Designer: How pick total value from footer group to use in detail group for calculate % of total

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I'm using Telerik Report Designer with SQL Server. I want create column Percentage like this sample:

```
    GroupDetail        Amount         Percentage
    Bank 1             1000.00         7.14%  (1000/14000)
    Bank 2             2000.00        14.28%  (2000/14000)
    Bank 3             4000.00        28.57%  (4000/14000)
    Bank 4             7000.00        50.00%  (7000/14000)
    GroupFooter TOTAL  14000.00
```

My SQL Query return 91 lines, and has the column Amount.

At GroupFooter to calculate Total I use:

```
    =Sum(Fields.Amount)
```

But at GroupDetail if I use same Sum(Fields.Amount) only take value of Amount for each line (same value).

My real problem is much complex. My SQL Query has more than 1000 lines, but I need solve this sample to apply in my real case.

> Resume:
>
> > Problem: At GroupDetail I can only access values from respective line.
> >
> > What I need: Way to take total value from GroupFooter to use in GroupDetail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem doing this:

At controller I used SQL Query to retrive the total I need and pass it as parameter using ViewBag to report.

Now I have % of total at each line of my detail.